# How can I get a Django template message displayed when I select a value from a dropdown list that matches a condition in the parent table?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I have a form whose constituent fields are foreign keys to respective parent models as shown below:

```
class vehicle(models.Model):
    STATUS = [
        (OPERATIONAL, ('Operational')),
        (GROUNDED, ('Grounded')),
        (NA, ('Not Applicable')),
    ]


    reg_no = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    operationalstatus = models.CharField (max_length=100, choices=STATUS, null=True)
```

Сhild model:

```
class managecar(models.Model):
    reg_no = models.ForeignKey(vehicle, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
```

forms.py

```
class manageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = managecar
        fields = '__all__'
```

I created a view as shown below and linked a URL to it to be called by ajax on the frontend to trigger a message if vehicle selected in the form is 'grounded'  but it returns 404 in the console while am expecting it returns a message of vehicle is grounded if I select a vehicle that is listed grounded in the parent model.

views.py

```
def validate_operation_status(request):
    grounded = request.GET.get('grounded', None)
    data = {
        'is_grounded': vehicle.objects.filter(operational_status__iexact='grounded').exists()
    }

    return JsonResponse(data)
```

ajax method :

```
$("#id_registration_no").change(function () {
    console.log( $(this).val() );
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/validate-status/',
        data: {
          'grounded': id_registration_no
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          if (data.is_grounded) {
            alert("This vehicle is grounded.");
          }
        }
    });
});
```

I'd appreciate to be guided in the right direction or someone to point out where I am failing.

Answer (score 0):

First, your views filtering was wrong, you did not filter which registration number are you looking, i think it must be :

**AJAX Code : (I've modified your variable name)**

```
$("#id_registration_no").change(function () {
    console.log( $(this).val() );
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/validate-status/',
        data: {
          'registration_no': id_registration_no
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          if (data.operational_status== 'Grounded') {
            alert("This vehicle is grounded.");
          }
        }
    });
});
```

**views.py :**

```
def validate_operation_status(request):
context={}
registration_no = request.GET.get('registration_no', None)

try:
    chck_tbl = vehicle.objects.get(reg_no=registration_no)
    context.update({'operational_status':chck_tbl.operationalstatus})
except:
    context.update({'operational_status':''})

return JsonResponse(data=context)
```

If it is not working, please try to check whether you are passing a correct/you can pass a value to your views.py if yes then check now if the data that you are passing from views to ajax was also correct.